# Copy specific subfolder from multiple folders using Powershell

Tags: powershell, copy-item

I am trying to do some Logs backup and struggle with ps1 command which can do this for me.

I have folder structure like this:

```
folder_root/
├── sub_a/
│   ├── Logs
│   ├── bootstrap.min.css
│   ├── Configuration
├── sub_b/
│   ├── Logs
│   └── Settings
└── sub_c/
    ├── Logs
    ├── Application
    ├── class.js
    └── other-file.html
```

And I need to extract only Logs folder from all subdirs and copy it into backup folder (which exists) respecting existing folder structure:

```
Backup-03-24/
├── sub_a/
│   └── Logs
├── sub_b/
│   └── Logs
└── sub_c/
    └── Logs
```

How to achieve this using Powershell? I am trying to use Copy-Item cmdlet with wildcard in path, but it does not work.

```
Copy-Item -Destination "C:\folder_root\*\Logs"
```

Comment: Please add a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is'n too hard to do. Just loop over the directories you get with `Get-ChildItem`, using a filter for the name of the folders you want to copy:

```
$sourcePath  = 'D:\folder_root'
$Destination = 'D:\Backup-03-24'
Get-ChildItem -Path $sourcePath -Filter 'Logs' -Recurse -Directory |
    ForEach-Object {
        $targetPath = Join-Path -Path $Destination -ChildPath $_.Parent.FullName.Substring($sourcePath.Length)
        $null = New-Item -Path $targetPath -ItemType Directory -Force
        $_ | Copy-Item -Destination $targetPath -Recurse -Force
    }
```

Result:

```
D:\BACKUP-03-24
+---sub_a
|   \---Logs
+---sub_b
|   \---Logs
\---sub_c
    \---Logs
```